# The word "normal" has started appearing on the upper right corner of my apps

Tags: desktop, graphics, release-hera

Did a little bit of updating and all of a sudden, the word "normal" is appearing in my apps.  See below.  Anyone have any idea how to get rid of this?

[image]

Comment: Just started showing up on my programs too and it's really annoying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must be having an nVidia graphics card. If so, open `nVidia X Server Settings` from the Applications menu, go to `OpenGL Settings` and uncheck "Enable Graphics API Visual Indicator".

Comment: It was already unchecked, I checked it and relaunched apps to test it and it just added more info to the right side of the window (like vblank for example).

I rolled back to 435 from 440 and that seemed to resolve the issue.  I'll skip 440 and wait to see whats going on with their big linux driver announcement I was just reading about.  Thanks for helping me look in the right place.

Comment: @Cerebrix Glad I could help! I am running 435 now as well, and that option is not even present in the nVidia Settings. The `big linux driver announcement`... are you refering to [the on-demand nVIdia option](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/08/nvidia-43517-linux-beta-driver-adds.html)?

Comment: I'm referring to this..

https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=NVIDIA-Open-Source-GTC-20